# removing first line from auto generated text output

Tags: java, python

I am using stanford core-nlp project, where they provide executable jar to perform various nlp stuff.

I write command which can read input from text file and write jar execution result to output.txt file.

command : `java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -client < input.txt > r.txt`

ACtually this command was for terminal, which was asking to print message on terminal

```
Input some text and press RETURN to NER tag it,  or just RETURN to finish.
```

But now as I read content from input file, I dont bother about that message

Issue with me is, above command write this message also to `r.txt`. IS there any way to exclude writing this message on r.txt? or any faster way to remove first line from r.txt once it is written.

I could not change jar file, otherwise I would have removed that message.

I am working on linux and executing above command from `.sh` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tail` will do the job:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -client < input.txt | tail -n +2 > r.txt
```

Comment: this is really cool, can you please add description what `| tail -n +2 ` does

Comment: Use the `man`, Luke.
`-n, --lines=K
              output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to
              output lines starting with the Kth`